# I'm getting an error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where' "

Tags: sql-server, wpf, syntax-error

I'm trying to update a SQL Server table (connected to a WPF project) and I'm getting the message

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword WHERE

What is wrong in my code?

```
private void Save_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Select("INSERT INTO [dbo].[Users](sumScore, doneLevels) VALUES ('" + ClsGlobal.sumScore + "','" + ClsGlobal.DoneLevels + "') WHERE [userName]= '" + ClsGlobal.userName + "'");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
    }
}

public DataTable Select(string selectSQL) 
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("dataBase");                                                                                         

    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source =(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = C:\Users\Avraham\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB\New Database.mdf ");

    sqlConnection.Open();                                           

    SqlCommand sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();          
    sqlCommand.CommandText = selectSQL;                            

    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand); 
    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);                                 

    return dataTable;
}
```

I'd try to get [and] or (and) near the word username, but this still didn't work.

Comment: Once you have this working, take some time out to read up on "sql injection attack", or "bobby drop tables".

Answer (score 2):

This query:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].Users
    VALUES ('" + ClsGlobal.sumScore + "','" + ClsGlobal.DoneLevels + "')
   WHERE [userName]= '" + ClsGlobal.userName;
```

Does not make sense.  `INSERT` inserts new rows, so `WHERE` is not appropriate.

Perhaps you want an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE dbo.Users
    SET sumScore = ?,
        DoneLevels = ?
    WHERE userName = ?;
```

You should be passing in `ClsGlobal.sumScore`, `ClsGlobal.DoneLevels`, and `ClsGlobal.userName` as parameters rather than munging the query string.

Comment: Adding that with SqlClient, parameter markers are named (e.g. `@SumScore`) rather than `?`.